# How can I implement tab bar controller, navigation controller and table view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking to create an application with 4 screens. The first screen will have a tab bar controller with two tabs. The second tab will go to 3rd screen. The 3rd screen will be a table view and when a cell is clicked, will push to the 4th screen and then I want to have a back button on 4th screen to navigate back to 3rd screen. The first screen will have a button that segues to the second screen and from the second screen there is a button that segues to 3rd screen which is the table view. The second screen should also have a back button to go back to first screen. How can I implement this via StoryBoard?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tutorials in the Apple developer site... but also on youtube... search for "Storyboard ios" you can find a step by step tutorial on how to manage the tableview controller and additional tableview to show details. I suggest also to look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/

Comment: I have used that raywenderlich site. I've been looking on YouTube as well with no luck. I have an app right now that i've been working on for a few weeks that currently has 4 screens. The first three screens are using a tab bar controller and the 4th screen is a navigation controller which allows me to get back to 3rd screen when I segue from 3rd to 4th screen. I wanted to modify my app to my above question but i've been having trouble doing it.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand so far from your question. You should first drag a Tab bar controller, that will by default have 2 tabs. Now on 1st tab or 1st view controller, place a button and make its push relation with the view controller you want. 2nd tab will open 3rd screen. Place a table view in it(view controller with 2nd tab or item). Make push relation from table view cell to the 4th screen(drag view controller and embed this view with navigation Controller). Embed all those views with navigation controller form where you want to turn back to previous view controller. Hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my issue. I wasn't using push to segue with my navigation controller and that was throwing everything off. Thanks for the help!